# AutoIt Split String

Tags: string, split, autoit

I have a String like this:

```
Info1|Info2
```

I want this String to be splitted by | and a it should return the second Info and the first one.
So I want one msgbox displaying Info1 and another one displaying Info2.
How can I do this?
I already tried

> StringSplit

But without any success...

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
#Region    ;************ Includes ************
#Include <Array.au3>
#EndRegion ;************ Includes ************
$str = 'Info1|Info2'
$array = StringSplit($str, '|', 2)
For $i = 0 To UBound($array) - 1
    MsgBox(64, $i, $array[$i], 1)
Next
_ArrayDisplay($array) ; example
```