# Split large string

Tags: string, text, autoit, multiline, multilinestring

I have a long text which needs to be converted to small strings so I can include it to an AutoIt script. If I include multi-line text it shows `error unterminated string`. So I should have:

```
"numbercharswillbe10" &_ "othernumbersofcharwillbe10" &_ etc..
```

How can I split it with `& _` -delimiters?

Answer (score 4):

### String concatenation

As per [Documentation - Language Reference - Operators](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_operators.htm):

> `&` Concatenates/joins two strings.
>
> `&=` Concatenation assignment.

Example:

```
Global $g_sText = "Long " & "string " & "here." & @CRLF

$g_sText &= "More text." & @CRLF

ConsoleWrite($g_sText)
```

### Multi line statements

As per [Documentation - Language Reference - Comments](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_comments.htm) (emphasis added, as it causes mentioned "unterminated string" error):

> Although only one statement per line is allowed, a long statement can span multiple lines if an underscore "`_`" preceded by a blank is placed at the end of a "broken" line. **String definition cannot be split in several lines, concatenation need to be used.**

Example:

```
Global Const $g_sText = "Long " & _
                        "string " & _
                        "here." & _
                        @CRLF & _
                        "More text." & _
                        @CRLF

ConsoleWrite($g_sText)
```

### Double-quotes

As per [Documentation - FAQ - Double quotes](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/faq.htm#3):

> If you want to use double-quotes inside a string then you must "double them up". So for every one quote you want you should use two. ...
>
> or use single quotes instead ...

[Examples](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/faq.htm#3) available from source.

### Defaults and limits

As per [Documentation - Appendix - Limits/defaults](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/LimitsDefaults.htm):

> `4095` Maximum size for a line of script.
>
> `2,147,483,647` Maximum string length.

As per [Documentation - Language Reference - Datatypes - Strings](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_datatypes.htm):

> All AutoIt strings use UTF-16 (in fact and more precisely UCS-2) encoding.

As per [Documentation - Intro - Unicode Support](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/unicode.htm):

> There are a few parts of AutoIt that don't yet have full Unicode support. These are:
>
> Send and ControlSend - Instead, Use ControlSetText or the Clipboard functions.
>
> Console operations are converted to ANSI.

### Alternatives

Alternatives to [hard coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) include [`ClipGet()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ClipGet.htm) and [`FileRead()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileRead.htm).

#### Text from clipboard

Example (select and copy text <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> first):

```
Global Const $g_sText = ClipGet()

ConsoleWrite($g_sText & @CRLF)
```

#### Text from file

Example (create `C:\my_long_string.txt` first):

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>

Global Const $g_sFile = 'C:\my_long_string.txt'
Global Const $g_sText = _TextFromFile($g_sFile)

ConsoleWrite($g_sText & @CRLF)

Func _TextFromFile(Const $sFile)
    Local       $hFile = FileOpen($sFile, $FO_READ + $FO_UTF8_NOBOM)
    Local Const $sData = FileRead($hFile)

    FileClose($hFile)
    Return $sData
EndFunc
```

### Split string

Alternatives to hard coded manual string splitting include [`StringSplit()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringSplit.htm), [`_StringExplode()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_StringExplode.htm) ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30324676/4157124)) and [`StringMid()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringMid.htm).

#### Structural

`StringSplit()` splits a string into array of:

- individual characters (on empty delimiter),
- words (on space  delimiter) or
- lines (on `@CRLF`, `@LF` or `@CR` delimiter).

#### Equal length

`StringMid()` returns part of a string. Can be used to split into parts of equal length. Example (no error checking, select and copy text <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> first):

```
#include <Array.au3>

Global Const $g_iSize  = 10
Global Const $g_sText  = ClipGet()
Global Const $g_aArray = _StringSplitEqual($g_sText, $g_iSize)

_ArrayDisplay($g_aArray)

Func _StringSplitEqual(Const $sText, Const $iSize = 1)
    Local Const $iLength = StringLen($sText)
    Local Const $iParts  = Ceiling($iLength / $iSize)
    Local Const $iRest   = -1; $iLength - ($iSize * Floor($iLength / $iSize))
    Local       $iStart  = 0
    Local       $iCount  = 0
    Local       $aArray[$iParts]

    For $i1 = 0 To $iParts - 1

        $iStart      = ($i1 * $iSize) + 1
        $iCount      = ($i1 < $iParts - 1) ? $iSize : ($iRest ? $iRest : $iSize)
        $aArray[$i1] = StringMid($sText, $iStart, $iCount)

    Next

    Return $aArray
EndFunc
```

### Join string

As per [documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArrayToString.htm):

> `_ArrayToString`
> Places the elements of a 1D or 2D array into a single string, separated by the specified delimiters

Example (add `_StringSplitEqual()` and select and copy text <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> first):

```
#include <Array.au3>

Global Const $g_iSize      = 10
Global Const $g_sStart     = '$sText = "'
Global Const $g_sEnd       = '"' & @CRLF
Global Const $g_sDelimiter = '" _' & @CRLF & '       & "'
Global Const $g_sText      = StringReplace(ClipGet(), @CRLF, '')
Global Const $g_aArray     = _StringSplitEqual($g_sText, $g_iSize)
Global       $g_sResult    = _ArrayToString($g_aArray, $g_sDelimiter)

$g_sResult = $g_sStart & $g_sResult & $g_sEnd
ConsoleWrite($g_sResult)
```

Returns:

```
$sText = "AutoIt v3 " _
       & "is a freew" _
       & "are BASIC-" _
       & "like scrip" _
       & "ting langu" _
       & "age design" _
       & "ed for aut" _
       & "omating th" _
       & "e Windows " _
       & "GUI and ge" _
       & "neral scri" _
       & "pting."
```