# Equivalent of Join in AutoIt

Tags: arrays, string, autoit

AutoIt has a function StringSplit that works just like Split in C# or Visual Basic, but I can't find the equivalent of joining an array of strings using a certain string in between.

So I would like to have the AutoIt equivalent of Visual Basic:

```
strResult = Join(strSplit, "<joiner>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArrayToString.htm):

> `_ArrayToString`
> Places the elements of a 1D or 2D array into a single string, separated by the specified delimiters

Example:

```
#include <Array.au3>

Global Const $g_aArray     = ['A', 'B', 'C']
Global Const $g_sDelimiter = '<joiner>'
Global Const $g_sString    = _ArrayToString($g_aArray, $g_sDelimiter)

ConsoleWrite($g_sString & @CRLF)
```

Returns:

```
A<joiner>B<joiner>C
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate each element of the input array of strings with string joiner. See example below.

Function:

```
Func Join($aSplit,$joiner)
    if not isarray($aSplit) then return 0

    local $res = ""

    for $i = 0 to UBound($aSplit)-1
        $res &= $aSplit[$i] & $joiner
    Next

    $res = StringTrimRight($res,StringLen($joiner))
    return $res
EndFunc
```

Testing:

```
$string = "some;text;here"
$split = StringSplit($string,";",2)

$res = Join($split,"--")
ConsoleWrite($res & @CRLF)
```