# Autoit ask for user input then paste that data

Tags: autoit

I would like to create an msgbox that asks for user data. Then take that data and paste it wherever I want. Example! Auto it will create a small box asking for the Username. the user will type in there name(PCUSER) and click ok on the box. The script will then take the NAME (PCUSER) and paste it in the location I choose!

I already created a box but I have 2 problems..

1) Cant make the "ok" button close the box

2) the script wont run anything other than generating the box!

Any advice would really be helpful!

Sidenote. I can make the script save as a notpad with the userinput inside but I cant get it to "Read" the text.

Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533865/4157124).

Answer (score 1):

If you want it somewhere specific, set it to a var. This puts it on the clipboard so you can paste it wherever you want:

```
ClipPut(InputBox("Username" , "Type Username"))
```