# Making 2 variables of 1

Tags: split, autoit

I'm trying to make 2 variables of one. This is the variable: "`12345678900&mtc`".

I need variables "`12345678900`" and "`mtc`".

Comment: You probably want to look at [StringSplit()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringSplit.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> … make 2 variables of one.

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `StringSplit()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringSplit.htm) :

> Splits up a string into substrings depending on the given delimiters.

Example:

```
Global Const $g_sString    = '12345678900&mtc'
Global Const $g_sDelimiter = '&'
Global Const $g_aArray     = StringSplit($g_sString, $g_sDelimiter)

Global Const $g_sMsgTpl    = '$g_aArray[1] = "%s"\n$g_aArray[2] = "%s"\n'
Global Const $g_sMsgRes    = StringFormat($g_sMsgTpl, $g_aArray[1], $g_aArray[2])

ConsoleWrite($g_sMsgRes)
```

Returns:

```
$g_aArray[1] = "12345678900"
$g_aArray[2] = "mtc"
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).

Answer (score 0):

also stringmid will get you there

```
local $str = "12345678900&mtc" , $var1 = StringMid($str , 1 , StringInStr($str , "&") - 1),  $var2 = StringMid($str , StringInStr($str , "&") + 1)

consolewrite($str & @CR & $var1 & @CR & $var2 & @CR)
```

also formatting the string into assigns via regular expression and executing it

```
execute(stringregexpreplace("12345678900&mtc" , '(.+?)&(.*)' , 'Assign("var1" , "$1") Assign("var2" , "$2")'))

ConsoleWrite(eval("var1") & @CR & eval("var2") & @CR)
```