# How to pass "document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache")" in Autoit As a Text

Tags: autoit

I tried Passing using `Send("")` as shown below and even I tried with `ControlSetText` also getting `Unknown FunctionName Error`. Please Help me.

```
send("document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache")")
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).

Answer (score 0):

there are two types of quoting, that are interchangable:

```
send('document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache")')
```

Alternatively you can escape the quotes:

```
send("document.execCommand(""ClearAuthenticationCache"")")
```