# AutoIT and quotes

Tags: autoit, wmic

I need to create AutoIT script which will call this:

```
wmic path win32_tcpipprinterport where "hostaddress = 'server1'"  set hostaddress="server2"
```

tried to combine quotes like this:

```
$CMD = 'wmic path win32_tcpipprinterport where ""hostaddress = ''server1''""  set hostaddress=""server2"" & pause'

RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & $CMD)
```

But still cannot make it working.
Please can you help ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> But still cannot make it working.

Example:

```
$sCmd = 'wmic path win32_tcpipprinterport where "hostaddress = ''server1''" set hostaddress="server2"'
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).