# How to split a string into an array of characters in AutoIt?

Tags: string, windows-10, autoit

To split a sentence or paragraph in AutoIt:

```
$origional = ClipGet()
Local $string = ClipGet()
Local $arrayofsubstrings = StringSplit($string, '!')
Local $substringcount = 1
Local $outToClipPut
Do
    $outToClipPut = $arrayofsubstrings[$substringcount]
    ClipPut($outToClipPut)
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}")
    Send(@CRLF)
    $substringcount = $substringcount + 1
    Sleep(300)
Until $substringcount = 100
```

I  already replaced newlines and whitespaces by '!', and '!!' with '!'. I want to split the string into an array of single characters, but I have nothing to replace with '!'.

I don't have a parameter to pass into `StringSplit($string, 'no parameter to pass in here')`. How to output individual characters in `$outToClip`?

Answer (score 1):

> "*but what if i want to split the string into an array of single characters? i have nothing to replace with '!' i don't have a parameter to pass into " StringSplit($string, 'no parameter to pass in here') " ...*"

As per [Documentation > Function Reference > `StringSplit()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringSplit.htm) :

> If you use an empty string "" for the delimiters, each character will be returned as an element.

Example :

```
$arrayofsubstrings = StringSplit($string, '')
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).