# Put double quotes inside double quotes in auto IT for selenium file upload

Tags: selenium, autoit

I am trying to run an Auto IT script wherein I need to put double quotes inside double quotes for multiple file upload. Below is my script.

```
ControlClick("Open","","SysTreeView321")
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",""docx file" "csv file" ")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

I am getting error on Line 3. Can anyone help?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",'"docx file" "csv file" ')
```